# Check length of field as user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, validation

I have seen this ability over the web and I wasn't quite sure how to search for it, a good example is sending a text message it will say as you are typing:

132/160 - and the 132 counter will increase until you hit your limit.

My question was is it possible to get working with javascript alone, no jQuery library? However if I have to use jQuery I will, perhaps a point to a good tutorial, or maybe it's simpler than that, or even some terms to search for it, Thanks.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, so everything that works in jQuery works in bare javascript.

Comment: Well I guess I meant without including the jQuery library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--This is your input box. onkeyup, call checkLen(...) -->
<input type="text" id="myText" maxlength="200" onkeyup="checkLen(this.value)">

<!--This is where the counter appears -->
<div id="counterDisplay">0 of 200</div>


<!--Javascript Code to count text length, and update the counter-->
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function checkLen(val){
        document.getElementById('counterDisplay').innerHTML = val.length + ' of 200';
    }
//--></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `oninput` event, where supported (all modern browsers, IE 9 and later) and `onpropertychange` for older Internet Explorers:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
if ("onpropertychange" in myInput && !("oninput" in myInput)) {
    myInput.onpropertychange = function () { 
        if (event.propertyName == "value")
            inputChanged.call(this, event);
    }
}
else
    myInput.oninput = inputChanged;

function inputChanged () {
    // Check the length here, e.g. this.value.length
}
```

*onkeyup* is not a suitable event for handling input, as there is a notable delay between the user entering text and your code noticing the change.  A user could even hold the key down (for repeating text on Windows devices), but your code would not handle it.

Comment: Ok, I like this answer a heck of a lot better. +1 And it's high time I learned some HTML5; `oninput` looks like a great event.

Comment: I like this answer too, in concept. I haven't had experience with the event other than using it on your blog. Just seems like a lot of code, for a simple task. I agree, though, that it is more often than not the desired effect people are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got a exact solution for your problem
The **countChar** function takes a textbox object and a div object. The div object will display how many characters are left.

```
function countChar(txtBox,messageDiv)
    {
        try
        {

            count = txtBox.value.length;
            if (count < 160)
            {
                charLeft = 160 - count;
                txt = charLeft + " characters left...keep typing!!";
                messageDiv.innerHTML="<font color=green>" + txt + "</font>";
            }
            else
            {
                messageDiv.innerHTML="<font color=red>Message is too long</font>";
            }
            }
            catch ( e )
            {

            }
    }

<INPUT type="text" id="txtMessage" 
    onkeyup="countChar(txtMessage,messagesuccess);" 
    onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13){document.getElementById('btnSendTextMessage').click();}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hook the [`onkeyup`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event of the text box.

You can then validate/check the length of the value of the text box and (if you want to display the counter to the user) update the counter display as necessary.

Comment: On second thought, go with @Andy E's answer. I'm only not deleting mine so people coming here on a search can see the counterpoint and still choose @Andy E's option.

Comment: Very chivalrous, I like your style :-) Thanks very much!

Comment: @Andy E: Just goes to show that even the most jaded of us can still learn a new thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution.

Assuming you have html code as follows

```
<textarea onKeyPress='return count(this);'></textarea>
<input type="text" id="info" value="0/160" />
```

Note: the id of the input/text field is info.

You need the following javascript method

```
function count(area){
    var proceed = area.value.length < 160;
    document.getElementById('info').value = area.value.length+"/160";
    return proceed;
}
```

Note: the id of the text field specified in the method and the size is 160.

Answer (score 0):

this code for general usage:

html:

```
<input type="text" name="noteTitle" id="noteTitle" maxlength="100"   onkeyup="checkLength(this,'titleLength')" />
<div id="titleLength">100</div>
```

JS:

```
//take field (fieldToCheckMax), and its counterID(titleLength)
function checkLength(fieldToCheckMax,counterID){

//get the maxallowed for the input
maxAllowed=fieldToCheckMax.getAttribute('maxlength');
//save the affected counter in a variable
counterID=document.getElementById(counterID);
//change the value based on the max allowed, to switch between green and red
counterID.innerHTML=colorChanger();
//the color based checker, to decide is it red or green
function colorChanger(){
    if(fieldToCheckMax.value.length < maxAllowed) {
        counterID.style.color='green';
        return maxAllowed-fieldToCheckMax.value.length;}
    else {
    counterID.style.color='red';
    return maxAllowed-fieldToCheckMax.value.length;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is a key up handler which checks for the length of the string inside the textarea. You can also provide a maxlength attribute for the textarea.

Once you detect that the string crosses 160 ( or wateva the limit is) characters, you could provide a alert box and then trim the string to its first 160 chars.

I'm not going to provide the code and spoon feed you. It can be easily found across the web.